# How can I regroup this two tables together

Tags: r

I want to regroup this two variables R (votefr, voteaut) together how can I do it? To have in fine only one variable with the french vote and the austrian vote (maybe votefraut).
(below the table of this two variables)

```
table(d$votefr)

Centre-droite Extreme-droite         Gauche 
           455            117            356 

table(d$voteaut)

 Centre-Droite Extreme-Droite         Gauche 
           424            208            545
```

The result that I want is:

```
table(d$votefraut)
Centre-Droite Extreme-Droite         Gauche 
       879           325               901
```

Comment: We could just add them? `table(d$votefr) + table(d$voteaut)` What is the expected output?

Comment: What is the expected output? Please provide reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If both columns are factors with the same levels, we can just add them:

```
table(d$votefr) + table(d$voteaut)
```

If they are character class or factor with different levels, we need convert them to factors with the same levels.

Comment: It's not the table that i want regroup, but the variable votefr and the variable voteaut. To have the distribution of the voters of this two countrys togheter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum up all votes across different countries, you can try

```
Reduce(`+`, Map(table, df))
```

Otherwise, you can check `table(df)`